# Python diccionario error en get

Tags: python, python-3.x

En el código siguiente siempre sale por el valor por defecto. No veo que hay mal. ¿Donde está el error?

```
def switch(value):
    funcs = {'A': lambda: 1,
             'B': lambda: 2,
             'C': lambda: 3,
             'D': lambda: 4}
    return funcs.get(value, default_case(value))

def default_case(value):
    raise Exception(f'Invalid value: {value}')
```

Este ejemplo es muy conciso, lambda debe contener más código. Pero si así no funciona con más código tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la funcion get mira primero el valor opcional antes de ponerse a buscar, así que independientemente de lo que tengas te va a saltar la excepción primero. Por tanto, meter algún valor que marque como erróneo y después meter un condicional, por ejemplo:

```
def switch(value):
funcs = {'A': lambda: 1,
         'B': lambda: 2,
         'C': lambda: 3,
         'D': lambda: 4}
a= funcs.get(value,0)
if a==0:
  default_case(value)
else: 
 return a

def default_case(value):
   raise Exception(f'Invalid value: {value}')
print(switch('A'))
```

Comment: No es necesario usar condicionales, siempre que lo que pases como valor opcional no sea la *ejecución* de una función... si pones los `()` a la derecha del handler de una función, python siempre va a ejecutarla y pasar como parámetro lo que obtenga de la misma. En el momento en que pasas un handler, ya no se ejecuta, simplemente anota que el valor opcional es lo que sea que devuelva la función pasada como parámetro y cuando lo necesita, la ejecuta.

Comment: debería ser `print(switch('A')())` para que se ejecute la función asociada.

Comment: Por cierto, de dónde sacas que la función get mira primero el valor opcional??? No creo que eso tenga mucho sentido. Un diccionario no es más que una tabla, primero mirará si la clave indicada existe, y si no es cuando mira el valor opcional.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema es que la función `get` cuando tiene un valor por defecto que necesita ser evaluado (Como una función) es ejecutado, por lo que tu función `default_case` siempre se ejecutará.

Una forma simple de resolver el problema es utilizando `or`, recuerda que en `Python` tanto `or` como `and` tienen la función de "corto circuito" ([Lectura recomendada](https://es.acervolima.com/tecnicas-de-cortocircuito-en-python/)) y por lo tanto si el primer valor es verdadero entonces ignorará el segundo elemento, que en este caso es la función `default_case`.

```
def switch(value):
    
    funcs = {'A': lambda: 1,
             'B': lambda: 2,
             'C': lambda: 3,
             'D': lambda: 4}
    return funcs.get(value)() or default_case(value)

def default_case(value):
    raise Exception(f'Invalid value: {value}')
```

**Nota adicional:** Para que la función lambda se ejecute hace falta que pongas paréntesis al final del `get`, de esta forma `funcs.get(value)()`. O la otra opción sería utilizar los paréntesis para llamar la función lambda en el `switch` de esta forma `switch('A')()`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra variación del mismo tema:

```
def switch(value):
    funcs = {'A': lambda: 1,
             'B': lambda: 2,
             'C': lambda: 3,
             'D': lambda: 4}
    if value in funcs:
        return funcs[value]()
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Invalid value: {value}')
```

Expresa más claramente la idea de que si la llave no existe, se genera la excepción.

Notese que la función retorna el resultado evaluado de la función deseada.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos los que habéis contestado. Vuestras respuestas me han llevado la solución, que pasa por que el return debe quedar de la forma:

```
return funcs.get(value, lambda: default_case(value))()
```

Me faltaban los paréntesis al final, para que ejecutará la función, ya que si no, devuelve la dirección de la función y no la ejecuta, y añadir el *lambda* en la función por defecto.

El código completo debe ser:

```
def switch(value):
    funcs = {'A': lambda: 1,
             'B': lambda: 2,
             'C': lambda: 3,
             'D': lambda: 4}
    return funcs.get(value, lambda: default_case(value))()

def default_case(value):
    return('?')
    #raise Exception(f'Invalid value: {value}')
```

Con un retorno en la función para los valores por defecto o lanzando una excepción. Al gusto.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que estás llamando a la función `default_case`, no pasándole el handler de la misma. Podrías hacer algo como esto por ejemplo:

```py
def switch(value):
    funcs = {'A': lambda: 1,
    'B': lambda: 2,
    'C': lambda: 3,
    'D': lambda: 4}
    # En vez de llamar a la función, le paso una lambda con la llamada
    return funcs.get(value, lambda: default_case(value))

def default_case(value):
    raise Exception(f'Invalid value: {value}')
    
print(switch('C')())
```

Esto imprime `3`, y si le pasas un valor incorrecto lanza la excepción.